# How to determine if every file in a folder (and its subfolders) exists in another folder

Tags: directory, undelete

Folder B is obtained from (a copy of) folder A by an undelete application such as extundelete and therefore its structure is messed up. How can I determine if every file in B and its subfolders exists somewhere in A as well?

Here I'm assuming files have preserved names but the same question can be asked for when file comparison is done using file contents only.

Comment: Maybe my script I posted [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/731172/367990) can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use tree  to see the visual structure like:

```
tree folderA
tree folderB
```

or you could use diff to see what files are different in each subfolders

```
diff folderA folderB
```

Comment: You can also use `diff` on the folders directly. In Linux (and other Unixes), everything is a file, so from `diff`s viewpoint, a directory is a list of files. Therefore, it can print out the differences between those lists.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck thanks for your remark. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough. You can think of B as A with its structures flattened (so (some of the) files in the  (nested) subdirectories of A are moved into B). I'm not sure how useful diff can be for this purpose.